# sql queries, java string

Tags: java, sql, struct

developing a web application using java. I have SQL queries with more than 40 lines ,using " , "+  at staring an end of query respectively. it is very difficult to convert string as query when i want to do any modifications in both  both conversions

Comment: `it is very difficult to convert string as query when i want to do any modifications` This is true. And sad. 40 lines of SQL all written by hand... Feel my condolence... But what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use PreparedStatement? If possible, use an ORM tool like hibernate. That will simplify your code (Of course there are other benefits).

Comment: i am handling already developed project, so now i cant move to struct

Answer (score 1):

If your facing trouble in maintaing the sql query then you could try moving to spring JDBC templace where you can store the query in a config/props file with placeholders/bind variables. This significantly reduces the errorneous part of constructing a string query.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generalise your queries by creating this kind of methods.
Example:

```
private String DBFormatter="'";

public String FormatSQl(String value)
{
      return DBFormatter + value + DBFormatter;

}
```